# How to hide sidebar warning "The value of the local variable is not used" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

The "The value of the local variable is not used" warning is really annoying as it hide breakpoints in the sidebar. The variable in question also gets underlined to highlight this warning so the sidebar icon is fairly redundant.

So is there any way to hide this warning in the sidebar?

Comment: The cleanest way to remove it is to remove the local variable, since it's not used. That's what Eclipse is suggesting you to do, to make your code cleaner.

Comment: They are not used because they get commented out for debugging purposes. I don't want to have to go deleting and rewriting these variables when debugging just so that I can have a clear sidebar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **Windows** > **preferences**
- **Java** > **Compiler** > **Error/Warnings**
- Open **"Unnecessary code"** group
- change **"Value of local variable is not used"** from **"Warning"** to **"Ignore"**

It will require a new build and it's done.

Of course, you must aware that you are ignoring that option and potentially increasing memory consumption and leaving clutter in your code.

Answer (score 7):

@SuppressWarnings("unused")

Add the above line of code before main() it will suppress all the warning of this kind in the whole program. for example

```
public class CLineInput 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
```

You can also add this exactly above the declaration of the variable which is creating the warning, this will work only for the warning of that particular variable not for the whole program. for example

```
   public class Error4 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int a[] = {5,10};
        int b = 5;
        try
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")     // It will hide the warning, The value of the local variable x is not used.
            int x = a[2] / b - a[1];
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException e)
        {
            System.out.println ("Division by zero");
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Array index error");
        }
        catch(ArrayStoreException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong data type");
        }
        int y = a[1] / a[0];
        System.out.println("y = " + y);

    }

}
```

Comment: That is good solution! Suppress just stupid warning from main.